# Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline Precompiling fails with asset_path wrong arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

Day one of dealing with Rails 3.1 asset pipelines and defeated!

Here is the latest in a long line of errors thrown out by the assets:precompile on the production machine:

`wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) for 'asset_path'`

This happens on the application.css file (which I think is the first one it is trying).

This is the contents of my application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
*/

.account-badge
{
    background-color: #B94A48 !important
}

.centered {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.container[role="main"] {
    padding-bottom: 300px;
}

.page-footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    padding-top: 17px;
}
```

Might be important to mention that I'm using [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) in a brand new app (not upgrade)

Comment: It's the call to asset_path in your .css files that is barfing,  find all 'asset_path' calls in your .css files and post them

Comment: Very strange, I'm getting the same error. `asset-path` expects 2 arguments, but what is the second argument. `image` works, also `"yes"` works, where is this used? Looking at github rails/sass-rails, it shows 1 argument https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=asset-path

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at your `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` file, which gets included by sprockets (`*= require_tree`) of your `application.css` file.

I guess the error is located by including the `@iconSpritePath` or the `@iconWhiteSpritePath`.

Edit:
The method needs two arguments:

```
asset-url("rails.png", image)  # becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
asset-path("rails.png", image) # becomes "/assets/rails.png"
```

hope that helps

Comment: I guess that is the reason as it contains what you're referring to. However the strange point is that the error states asset_path needs 2 arguments and got only 1. All the asset_path instances in my app have 1 argument and I don't know what this second argument should be as this function takes in only one argument.